# PrimeFaces Slider 'for' value not working in a dataTable

Tags: primefaces, datatable, slider

Hello guys I'm trying to create a data table where people can set a value between 1 and 10 for each row:

```
<p:dataTable id="coteTable" value="#{editEvaluationView.evaluation.listCote}" var="cote">

        <p:column colspan="10">

            <p:inputText id="cote_#{cote.critere.code.trim()}"
                                    value="#{cote.valeur}" />
            <p:slider minValue="1" maxValue="10"
                                    for="cote_#{cote.critere.code.trim()}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column>
                <p:inputText id="commmentaire" value="#{cote.observations}" />
        </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

But it doesn't recognize the id (`cote_CRT001` is the first `cote_#{cote.critere.code.trim()}` value):

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Cannot find component for expression "cote_CRT001" referenced from "formEditEval:coteTable:0:j_idt120".
```

I really don't know what to try anymore. Does anybody have an idea why it's not working?

Comment: Simply use `id="cote"` and `for="cote"`.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634156/how-to-find-out-client-id-of-component-for-ajax-update-render-cannot-find-compo

Comment: I don't know why I complicated it so much...
Thank you Jasper for your help.

Comment: @JasperdeVries: Why not create this as an answer? ;-)

Comment: @Kukeltje done. I was not sure to flag it as duplicate and didn't feel an answer was really needed. But I someone just copy pastes your comment (and manages to get an error in it) I'm happy to do so.

Comment: duplicate was indeed better ;-). Upvoted never the less

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `dataTable` is a naming container, so components within it will be prepended with the `dataTable`'s `id`. Also, each iteration of data presented in the table (each row) will have effect of the generated `id`s. So there is no need for you to try to create unique `id`s. If you simply use `cote` of the `inputText`'s `id`. Since a form is also a naming container, it will be generated as `formId:coteTable:0:cote` in the first row, `formId:coteTable:1:cote` in the second row, etc. In your `slider` you can simply use `for="cote"` because you are referencing a component in the same naming container.

So, simply write:

```
<p:dataTable id="coteTable" value="#{editEvaluationView.evaluation.listCote}" var="cote">
    <p:column colspan="10">
        <p:inputText id="cote" value="#{cote.valeur}" />
        <p:slider minValue="1" maxValue="10" for="cote" />
    </p:column>
    ...
</p:dataTable>
```

See also

- [How to find out client ID of component for ajax update/render? Cannot find component with expression "foo" referenced from "bar"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634156/how-to-find-out-client-id-of-component-for-ajax-update-render-cannot-find-compo)